Fat scroller thumb decreases in size as recyclerview items/data increases in size
I implemented a fast scroller within my recyclerview.
Recyclerview
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/nature_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

However I've noticed that as the dataset/recyclerview items increase in numbers. The scroll thumb shrinks as well. This is obviously a problem for users, because it'll eventually become impossible to press the thumb. I have tried this other library. The "implementation 'com.zhanghai.android.fastscroll:library:1.1.2'
" but I cannot for the life of me get it to work as AS keeps telling me it can't find it.

Isn't that how the scroll thumb always works? I'd expect it to have some kind of minimum size so that it doesn't shrink too much... but on most platforms, its size tends to represent the relationship between visible:total.

I was just checking on this, and it actually doesn't have a minimum, which is just bad design. It uses the smaller of either the RecyclerView's height, or the RecyclerView's height squared divided by the (estimated) total height of the items: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/FastScroller.java#L359. I have no idea where that calculation comes from.

As for the other library, its latest release is 1.3.0 (link), so if you're lucky, bumping the version might help. However, I have a hunch that it was published on JCenter, and that shutdown completely a while ago, so it's probably no longer available anywhere. You could clone the repo and build it yourself locally, though.

Thanks. I'll use the latest release to see if that helps.

Oops, hang on. It's just a typo. Should be "me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll:library", with me, not com. I just downloaded it successfully. You probably want 1.3.0 anyway, though.
